# App crashes when I call a constructor in an Activity

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and I am trying to build a Notepad app.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     String title = findViewById(R.id.textView3).toString();
     String note_content = findViewById(R.id.textView).toString();

     FileOutputStream outputStream;

     try 
       {
           outputStream = openFileOutput(title, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           outputStream.write(note_content.getBytes());
       } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
      catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
          MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(title);
    }
    });
```

This is the button a user clicks to save the note. Once the code saves the note, it should send the Title to MainActivity so that it can be sent to Recycleview Adapter - this will display it in viewholder as a text.

Presently, when I run the code, it crashes - however, when I remove the constructor, the app works fine.
     `( MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(title);)`

```
Error:
     10-02 02:39:13.822 27279-27279/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-02 02:39:13.824 27279-27279/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quicknote, PID: 27279
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quicknote/com.example.quicknote.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.quicknote.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2337)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.quicknote.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
10-02 02:39:20.081 27279-27279/com.example.quicknote I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27279 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to instantiate activity. Because you can't start an activity like this. You have to use intent to start activity. To sent "title" use intent extra.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivty.this);
intent.putExtra("title", title);
startActivty(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the error message:

> java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor

A zero argument constructor is required for the Android system to instantiate an Activity. You should never be manually calling an Activity constructor yourself since only the system can properly create an Activity.

The [Parcelables and Bundles documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles) details the correct way of sending information to an Activity using the extras `Bundle`.

Comment: so you mean we cannot create are own constructor instead use Intent

Comment: Yep, you can't use your own constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

If it is, you have to retrieve the title from your extras from onCreate() of MainActivity instead from the constructor.

Something like that:

```
     //that code instead of your MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(title); line
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActualActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    startActivity(intent);


    //That code in the onCreate method of your MainActivity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String title = extras.getString("title");

    }
```

Comment: yes my activities are in Manifest.xml file. My app only crashes when i use the constructor to send "title" to MainActivity